# How can i do constant check on c#?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

i'm a c# begginer and i need help to do a constant check on windows forms application.
I did this code but i don't know where i can paste it.

```
while(true)
{
    if(checkconn == true)
    {
        labelcheck.Text = "Connected";
    }
    else
    {
        labelcheck.Text = "Not Connected";
    }
}
```

I already tried to put it on:

```
private void loginform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

and:

```
public loginform()
{
    InitializeComponent();            
}
```

but in both cases the application do not run because it runs on an endless loop.

Comment: Instead try text changed event if it's available for Label. This would save you CPU cycle no loop would require but an event handler will do the job.

Comment: i add the timer, but it create a problem to me. i can't click in any button

Comment: It's likely that you're unable to use your UI (click a button) because you're running your checks on the UI thread. Try running your checks on a separate thread or [backgroundworker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker). And you can use delegates to manipulate your UI from the separate thread.

Comment: thx guys. i'll work on that

Comment: It would be better to register to a relevant event that triggers when the connection state changes, and do stuff when that event fires.

Comment: can you help me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
readonly BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();

public loginform()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    e.Result = checkconn == true ? "Connected" : "Not Connected";
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    label.Text = e.Result as string;
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync(); // loops endlessly
}
```

Comment: thx! it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

To summarise the comments posted - it would be worth using a timer in your form if you can afford to be checking every so often (as opposed to all the time) and if you did not plan on doing a lot of processing during the check. The problem is that if you plan to do a fair amount of processing, you will not be able to use the UI as the current thread that the UI is operating in, is being used to do the processing of the check. If that is the case, then as @Ernest advised, it would be worth performing your checks on a separate thread. This way you could be constantly checking using something similar to the code that you already have (but placed inside of the `DoWork` block of a `BackgroundWorker`).
For example:

```
private void myBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(checkconn == true)
        {
            labelcheck.Text = "Connected";
        }
        else
        {
            labelcheck.Text = "Not Connected";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i already try this, but nothing happened.

Comment: You need to give the command to the `BackgroundWorker` to start doing work.